# Proof for Step Functions

Tags: real-analysis

I've got the following question:

> Show that a function $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a step function if and only if the following conditions hold:
>
> (a) $\varphi$ is continuous except at finitely many points on $\mathbb{R}$;
>
> (b) $\varphi$ takes only finitely many distinct values;
>
> (c) $\varphi(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$

For the $(\implies)$ direction it seems somewhat straight forward. Supposing $\varphi$ is a step function then there exists a partition $P = \{x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n\}$ such that $\varphi(x) = 0$ if $x > x_n$ or $x < x_0$ which implies (c). As $\varphi$ is a step function, it is continuous except possibly at the points $x_0, ..., x_n$, which implies (a). Finally, as a step function can only have a finite number of steps, this implies (b).

The ($\Longleftarrow $) direction is where I'm having trouble. Suppose we have a function $\varphi$ satisfying (a),(b) and (c). Then (c) and (b) imply that a partition exists whereby outside of the partition the value takes $0$, and (a) implies that we can form a partition which 'aligns' with the points of discontinuity in $\mathbb{R}$. (b) also implies that there are a finite number of steps. It's at this point it seems like all the criteria of a step function is satisfied but the proof seems a bit too straightforward.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this finite number of points of discontinuity. This leaves you with finitely many open intervals $I_k$. On each interval $I_k$, $f$ is continuous. Now, in view of the intermediate value theorem, what kind of function $f$ must be on $I_k$ if its range contains finitely many distinct values? Once you have this figured out, the rest follows easily.

**Note:**  b) and c) alone don't imply the existence of such a partition into intervals. What about $f(x)=1_\mathbb{Q}(x)1_{[0,1]}(x)$? You need to use a).

Comment: Yeah, if the range contains finitely many distinct values, and it's continuous, it must be a straight-line/constant in the interval.

Comment: @Noble Right. So you have finitely many points, plus finitely many intervals on which the function is constant.